# nodejs convert timestamp string into date with custom timezone and to UTC

Tags: javascript, node.js, timezone

Suppose i get the value `'2014-03-03 16:20:20'` as an input, I'd like to convert it 
to it's real time with timezone (i.e, node sits in Europe , but timestamp was collected in America), and after that I'd like to get the UTC representation of the real value.

Any idea what packages can help? Tried moment.js with no luck..

Comment: you requirement is getting time from client and trust that instead of using server time?

Comment: requirement is get user's date in 'YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm:ss' format, convert it to a UTC date according user's timezone

Comment: Are you collecting the input in a web browser?  Why not just convert to UTC there, so you don't have to involve time zones at all?  Why does it have to be done on in node.js server side code?

Comment: because it's not a browser, it's a legacy code on hardware which cannot be modified and always set to a particular and fixed TZ.

Comment: Related: [How to initialize javascript date to a particular timezone](http://stackoverflow.com/q/15141762/634824)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

finally found the answer with `momentjs-timezone` ,

which is kinda funny since you wont get a event a hint about on the mainsite http://momentjs.com/timezone/ but you can find it on http://github.com/moment/moment-timezone

anyhow here's how you do it :

```
var tz0 = moment.tz("2014-03-03 16:20:20", "Asia/Jerusalem")
var tz1 = moment.utc(tz0);


console.log(tz0.format('YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm:ss'));
console.log(tz1.format('YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm:ss'));
```

and the output as you can see respectivly

```
2014-03-03 04:20:20
2014-03-03 02:20:20
```

Answer (score 0):

```
// moment.js

var utc = moment('2014-03-03 16:20:20','YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss', 'us');
// or timezone string pass from client

var eu = utc.zone("+02:00");
var eu = utc.zone("-02:00");
```

Comment: what if i don't know the zone time difference ("+02:00")?
what if i want to pass the "us" time and convert to local, and then to UTC?

Comment: you check, preload a table with time diff. select the one you need at runtime. eu timezone is not that many

Answer (score 0):

momentjs may help you. Like the following:

1. Could you format the input with ISO date plus timezone info, like 2014-03-03T16:20:20-05:00 (supposing you get from local time at GMT-5 timezone)
2. Then call: **moment.parseZone('2014-03-03T16:20:20-05:00').zone(1).format()** (supposing you want to get local time at GMT+1 timezone)

Hope that help,
Ron

Answer (score 0):

[Timezone](http://bigeasy.github.io/timezone/) is an elegant module for this.

```
var tz = require("timezone/loaded");
var formattedDate = tz(unformattedTimestamp, '%d %B %Y, %-I:%M %p', "Europe/Amsterdam");
```

You can use [bootstraphelper](http://bootstrapformhelpers.com/timezone/) to capture user's timezone.